# As nibble for 4-bit, octet for 8-bit, is there a english word for 2-bit or 3-bit?

Tags: terminology

And, though the length of a machine *word* is dependent, but it's often 16-bit long. Is there english words explicitly defined for 2-bit, 3-bit, and 16-bit?

Comment: Dibit and tribit ? These terms are used in communications for modulation techniques which include several bits per state.

Comment: How about "doublet" and "triplet", along the same lines as "octet"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, a [`short`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29#Common_integral_data_types) refers to a 16-bit integer, but that's not guaranteed. A `short` only needs to be `char <= short <= int` in terms of bit size.

Another term suggested by that Wikipedia article is `halfword`, but I've never seen anyone use that term.

The Jargon file proposes [`crumb`](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nybble.html) (and some others, tongue firmly in cheek) for 2-bit datatypes, but doesn't have anything for 3 bits.